# Многопоточность telebot python

Tags: python, telebot, threading

Мне нужно запустить некоторое (меняющееся) количество ботов в telegram. Мой код не работает. Как это исправить?

```
def start_bot(*args):
   token = a.bot_token.split()[0]
   bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
        
        
   bot.infinity_polling()
        
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_fun(message):
    bot.send_message( message.chat.id, 'message', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=webAppKeyboard())


threading.Thread(target=start_bot, args=(a.bot_token)).start()
```

Ошибка:

```
    File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SubPro\SubPro\pages\views.py", line 21, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
     ^^^
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined
```

Comment: У вас используется необъявленный декоратор. Для того, чтобы ваш код заработал, нужно объявить бота вне метода.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
import telebot
import threading

def start_bot(token):
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start_fun(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'message', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=webAppKeyboard())

    bot.infinity_polling()

bot_token = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"
threading.Thread(target=start_bot, args=(bot_token,)).start()
```